# weighted binning of the data with uncertainties

Tags: python, numpy, astropy, binning

I need help with binning observational data that have uncertainties. I have an .csv file of data *(X,Y)* with the errors *delta_Y*. I need to bin the data as a weighted average of two adjacent values of the data column *Y* (i.e., by pairs - the first and second value, the third and fourth, etc.), where the "weight" will calculated from the measurement errors (sigma - *delta_Y*) of corresponding values.

Anyone knows how to do this? Is there a Python function available that could do this?

All help would be highly appreciated:) Many thanks!

I'm a beginner in python, but I understand the basic syntax. I understand how I could calculate it manually, but a large amount of data (several hundred rows) requires automated processing.

Comment: "StackOverflow is not a code-writing service." You need to show your attempt.